# SSH or telnet on other ports is not working from a specific network

Tags: ssh, firewall, ubuntu-16.04, telnet

We have an Lenovo server working well since one and a half year.
Sudenly, we started having issues to connect to it from our office network.
I reinstalled ubuntu 16.04 sever on it. It has two ethernet ports, one used for the public ip and another for the internal network.

When trying to connect with a mobile network or one specific server from our local office network, all works well, but as soon as I am trying to connect to it from my or my colleagues local PCs, or another office server, I am getting a timeout, both on ssh port, 80, 443 etc.

The server side has a firewall, but that's not the issue as from the same network, the connection works from some machines, but not from others?

Thank you.

Comment: You will have to trace network packets and work your way back. It is likely one of two things: firewall or routing issue. Without a detailed network topology it is hard to tell.

Comment: I restsrted the ssh service, once again, and it seems to work well now, let's see for how much time. I will run a traceroute if this happens again. If still ok in 1 week, I will close the ticket.

Comment: Hi Eckes, worked well since today, and now not working anymore. Any suggestion?

Comment: Please paste the output of `route -n` so we can see where your system is trying to send network data.  I suspect the issue is merely that your interfaces are a little confused about where to send which packets.